# Booting issue & Boot-Repair not working

Tags: boot, mount, grubrescue, boot-repair, badblocks

I have problems with booting Ubuntu 14 on my computer. Normal booting ends to grub rescue mode (can't read something from hard drive). Actually only way I have managed to boot my computer is to use Linux Mint compatibility mode (booting with USB stick). This way I did save my personal files after "read-only" mounting the correct partition (although when I did that the correct partition was sdb1, now it seems to be changed sda1 and problems to do the mounting same way as before). Normal mounting failed because of unknown file system type. I think there was some bad super blocks.

Now I would like to know is there anyway how to use again my Ubuntu 14? I tried boot-repair according to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair, but I didn't get the "Recommended repair" button. Instead I got the following boot info summary (to get help by email or forum):

http://paste2.org/0xGBMXmY

My computer makes buzzing noises so maybe the hard drive is just physically broken and there is nothing to do?

Answer (score 1):

There is no working Ubuntu operating system installation on the hard disk.
You have to reinstall Ubuntu ... I am sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.
When Ubuntu runs, your're done ... if not, maybe the disk in fact is broken.