# Failing GRUB installation and Boot-repair

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

Here is my earlier issue: [Booting issue & Boot-Repair not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718067/booting-issue-boot-repair-not-working/718075#718075)

Despite of possible hard drive problems I have tried to install Linux Mint to my laptop via USB (Linux Mint because I'm not aware of if it is possible to install also Ubuntu from such a compatibility mode like Linux Mint). I modified my partition table so that I used sdb5 and sdb6 as my external and swap partitions (to avoid file system creation in partition sdb1 that always failed in the beginning of the installation). I almost finished the installation, but got error message:

"Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sdb. Executing 'grub-install /dev/sdb' failed. This is a fatal error!"

Despite of this message I got also message that installation finished and I they gave me option to restart. After pushing that button computer got stuck. No surprise was that nothing showed up when I tried to boot again after forced shut down and without installation USB. So back to USB Linux Mint. I tried to fix/re-install GRUB using boot-repair. I did the "Recommended repair" and finally encountered "An error occured during the repair" and got the following link:

http://paste2.org/NwJFkc0Z

Is there a way how I could install/fix GRUB so that it would work? And/Or should I try again the whole Linux installation?

Actually now when I boot the computer I can access The GNU GRUB version 2.02...., but so far I have not been able to boot from there (seems to me that some commands that should be used are not working).

Comment: You can't install to a broken drive.  Also this site is about Ubuntu, not mint.

Comment: Well I have not been completely sure that my drive really is broken. It seemed to me that everything else could be installed but not GRUB. And I think the installation is similiar to ubuntu and mint.

Comment: The "Input/Output error" is a strong indicator that the drive is in fact, broken.  Check `dmesg` for more detailed error reporting, and you can check the drive's SMART health status in the disks utility.

Answer (score 0):

> Despite of possible hard drive problems

Magically fixing broken hardware is not one of Ubuntu's features. If you replace your broken hardware and continue to have problems, please post back. Likewise if you investigate further and discover that your disk is not broken.

Note also that a broken hard disk is not something to be taken lightly. If your computer holds important data, you should *not* be entrusting that data to a suspect hard disk. A flaky video card? Fine; your data will be reasonably safe. A mouse that moves erratically is an annoyance, nothing more. A damaged hard disk is *worse* than useless.